# Can't drop element in previously hidden cdkDropList

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

When I start dragging the element, I show the target container for the drop and change the size of the original container to leave place to the drop zone.

What happens is that the size of the original container that is being considered is the one at the moment of the drag start.

When I drop my element, he's being dropped in the original container.

```
<div cdkDropListGroup>
  <div class="list-container" [ngClass]="{ 'on-drag': dragStartEtat }" id="baseList" cdkDropList
    [cdkDropListData]="list1" #baseList="cdkDropList" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="line" (cdkDragStarted)="dragStart($event)" (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnd($event)" cdkDrag
      *ngFor="let e of list1">{{ e }}</div>
  </div>

  <div [hidden]="!dragStartEtat" #archive="cdkDropList"  cdkDropList  class="cdk-archive"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="dropArchive($event)">
    Glissez déposez pour archiver
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.list-container {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 325px);
    max-height: calc(100vh - 325px);
    overflow: auto;
}

.dessus {
    background-color: orange;
    min-height: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
}

.cdk-archive {
    color: white;
    transition: 0.5s;
    text-align: center;
    height: 15vh;
    background-color: rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.8);

    .cdk-drag-placeholder {
        display: none !important;
    }
}

.on-drag {
    min-height: calc(100vh - (325px + 15vh))!important;
    max-height: calc(100vh - (325px + 15vh))!important; 
    overflow: auto;  
}
```

```
drop(event) {
    console.log('drop');
}

dropArchive(event) {
    console.log('dropArchive');
}

dragStart(event: CdkDragStart) {
    this.dragStartEtat = true;
}

dragEnd(event) {
    this.dragStartEtat = false;
}
```

There is no problems if the target container is shown from the start.

What is expected is for the dropArchive to be triggered when dropping in 'archive' zone. However the drop on 'baseList' is the one still being triggered.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong or a solution to get around this behavior ?

Here's the full working example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/hidden-drop-zone

Comment: what should be expected output? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Hi Majid! I'm having the same problem myself. `cdkDragDrop` indeed seems to consider the height or position of the `DropList` at drag start. I am trying to drag a `cdkDrag` item into a `cdkDropList` found in a subtree of a Tree component. I hover over the category (an `li` when speaking of DOM structure) which causes the subtree to collapse. Attempting to then drop the `cdkDrag` preview into the `cdkDropList` that just opened causes the item to not get dropped into the droplist at all.

Have you been able to resolve this issue at all?

Comment: In my case, I was lucky because I could use the absolute position of the screen which IMO not the best solution (if there's any). I don't know if it helps you with your problem!